# jquery ajax json error 'provisional headers are shown'

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I cant get my json data even in a simple way using the jquery api example and as a result i have only 2 console logs before and after request. I used local host denwer and xampp for test. Turn off all of my extensions, because i have an idea it was adblock blocking my request...
P.S. sorry for bad English

```css
{
 "articles": [
   {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "How to build a website"
   },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Reading json with jquery"
   },
   {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Learning javascript"
   },

 ]
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>JSON</title>
 <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
 <script>
  console.log('before request');
  $.getJSON( "ajax/articles.json", function( data ) {
   console.log('success');
   console.log(data.articles);
  });
  console.log('after request');
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
```

[image]